# Как аппроксимировать нелинейную функцию в Python

Tags: python

Здравствуйте.У меня есть массив данных.Их нужно аппроксимировать использовав эту функцию:x=Ae^(-ht) sin(2π/T t+ф).
В массиве данных указан год и сопуствующий ему темп роста.Если будет нужно я напишу данные.Пожалуйста помогите!
Данные[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016.
1 случай:1,-7.9,2.8,3.2,2.2,3.9,2.7,2.5,6.2,5.7,3.6,3.2,-0.4,5.6,3.3,3,2.6,5.9,-2.3,-1.1.
2 случай:3.2,-18.8,-5,0.7,5.5,0,4.2,3.4,1.3,12.2,1.4,11.3,0.3,2.9,5.1,4.9,-3.5,5.1,-1.9,-2.1
3 случай:-1.7,-13.5,7.4,6.5,-3.9,2.6,0.3,0.5,-1.5,8,0.8,4.5,1.9,2.8,-2.8,3.4,-2.2,-1.1,-11.3,7.7

Comment: Вы хотите узнать как найти параметры (A,T,ф) у заданной нелинейной функции (exp×sin), имея массив данных (x, t), который эта функция с какой-то точностью описывает?

Comment: связанный вопрос [How do I fit a sine curve to my data with pylab and numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16716302/4279)

Comment: пример для вашей функции: [Robust nonlinear regression in scipy](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html)

Comment: @jfs вы совершенно правы!мне нужно чтобы программа подобрала эти параметры(А,Т,ф). Я прям совсем новичок в программировании(в частности в Python) и мой уровень это написание простых калькуляторов,но программа мне нужна сейчас, дабы построить необходимый мне график.Я буду весьма Вам признателен,если вы поможете мне систематизировать присланную Вами статью.
Если вы не можете помочь,то все равно огромное спасибо,Вам.

Comment: @KirillDotsenko, вы можете выложить ваши данные на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: @KirillDotsenko: если вы нажмёте на ссылку, то там по шагам показано как график построить и сам график присутствует и код, который его строит.  Практически, только `fun()` под свои параметры поправьте (`x[0] * np.exp(-h * t) * np.sin(tau * t / x[1] + x[2]) - y`) и передайте `t_train`, `y_train`, которые у вас есть.

Comment: @MaxU могу.могу и здесь Вам написать данные.их не так много

Comment: @jfs спасибо Вам большое!я попытаюсь сделать

Comment: @KirillDotsenko, если данных не много - укажите их в вопросе или в виде ссылки на файлообменник...

Comment: @MaxU Сделано.указал в описании данные.если вдруг возникнут проблемы я постараюсь на файлообменник выложить.
Заранее благодарю Вас за оказанную помощь.Если у Вас будет возможность выложить код,то пожалуйста прошу,Вас,окажите данную помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(t, A, h, T, phi):
    return A*np.exp(-h*t)*np.sin(2*np.pi/T*t + phi)

t = np.array([1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016])
y = np.array([1,-7.9,2.8,3.2,2.2,3.9,2.7,2.5,6.2,5.7,3.6,3.2,-0.4,5.6,3.3,3,2.6,5.9,-2.3,-1.1])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, t, y, (1e3, 1e-2, 1., -1e1), maxfev=10**6)    
A, h, T, phi = popt

print('A={0}\nh={1}\nT={2}\nphi={3}'.format(*tuple(popt)))

plt.scatter(t, y, s=30, color='orange')
plt.plot(t, func(t, *popt))
```

Параметры:

```
A=2.5799396598541523e+33
h=0.037592823141341276
T=1.0293760398048617
phi=348.9653603351754
```

График:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE:**

> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp

это предупреждение о том, что во время оптимизации произошло переполнение в функции `np.exp()`, например `np.exp(10**4)` - выдаст такое предупреждение

> Можно ли сделать чтобы график был периодичнее?

на самом деле периодичность будет заметна на большем интервале:

```
plt.scatter(t, y, s=30, color='orange')
x = np.arange(1980, 2040)
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!Но у меня два вопроса.1)Когда я забиваю код то мне выдает данное сообщение:overflow encountered in exp.2)Данные на амплитуду,коэффициент затухания,период и фазу он выдает у меня такие же как и у Вас.МОжно ли сделать чтобы график был периодичнее?@MaxU

Comment: Вы можете ответить на 2 вопроса которые я Вам задал выше?

Comment: о простите.я не сразу заметил правку